# calling shmdt on a daemon process

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a shared memory segment that the parent and child process read/write to. The child process is actually like a daemon process thats running in the background.

When I did shmat, I also called shmctl to mark the shared memory for deallocation in both process.

However when the parent process is stopping, I can call shmdt to detach the parent from the shared segment. But how do I call shmdt in the child(daemon) process? Without it, the memory will not be deallocated even when both processes are killed.

Comment: in the Linux man page for `shmat()`, the "notes" section says "Upon _exit(2), all attached shared memory segments are detached from the process."  On the man page for `shmctl()`, under the section for IPC_RMID, it says "Mark the segment to be destroyed.  The segment will actually be  destroyed  only after  the  last  process  detaches  it (i.e., when the shm_nattch member of the associated structure shmid_ds is zero).  The caller must be the owner or creator of the segment, or be privileged.  The buf argument is ignored."

Comment: From the question, I can understand that you want to detach shared memory from child process as well when parent process exits.
If this is what you want, then you can write a signal handler in parent and child process to catch any signal and from that signal handler in parent process you can send another signal to child process, then from signal handler of the child process, you can call shmdt.

This is what I understood from the question! If this is not what you want then please add more explanation.